# Show/hide li by clicking on p element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I would like to have the possibility to show/hide an ul by clicking on p. My HTML looks like this:-

```
<li class="type_unknown depth_2">
   <p class="tree_item branch">
        <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1123">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;Daoust University Refreshs
        </a>
    </p>
   <ul id="yui_3_15_0_4_1495615549528_188">
      <li class="type_unknown depth_3">
         <p class="tree_item leaf">
            <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1257"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;REFRESH DIVERSITEIT</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="type_unknown depth_3">
         <p class="tree_item leaf">
            <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1230"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;REFRESH DOELGROEPENVERMINDERINGEN</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="type_unknown depth_3" id="yui_3_15_0_4_1495615549528_187">
         <p class="tree_item leaf wiki_newentry" id="yui_3_15_0_4_1495615549528_186">
            <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1167"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;REFRESH FEESTDAGEN</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="type_unknown depth_3">
         <p class="tree_item leaf">
            <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1270"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;REFRESH VREEMDELINGEN</a>
        </p>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

You can see I have a **p tag** in my **li** and also an **ul tag**. The layout looks like this:

[image]

But I would like to have the possibility to have it open or closed.

**Open**:

[image]

**Closed:**
[image]

So when you click on it, the content opens or closes. How can I do this?

Comment: Try [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below :-

```
$('.tree_item').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

example:-

```js
$('.tree_item').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

```css
ul,li{
list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="type_unknown depth_2">
   <p class="tree_item branch">
        <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1123">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;Daoust University Refreshs
        </a>
    </p>
   <ul id="yui_3_15_0_4_1495615549528_188">
      <li class="type_unknown depth_3">
         <p class="tree_item leaf">
            <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1257"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;REFRESH DIVERSITEIT</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="type_unknown depth_3">
         <p class="tree_item leaf">
            <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1230"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;REFRESH DOELGROEPENVERMINDERINGEN</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="type_unknown depth_3" id="yui_3_15_0_4_1495615549528_187">
         <p class="tree_item leaf wiki_newentry" id="yui_3_15_0_4_1495615549528_186">
            <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1167"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;REFRESH FEESTDAGEN</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="type_unknown depth_3">
         <p class="tree_item leaf">
            <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1270"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;REFRESH VREEMDELINGEN</a>
        </p>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>

<li class="type_unknown depth_2">
   <p class="tree_item branch">
        <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1123">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;Daoust
        </a>
    </p>
   <ul id="yui_3_15_0_4_1495615549528_188">
      <li class="type_unknown depth_3">
         <p class="tree_item leaf">
            <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1257"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;REFRESH</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="type_unknown depth_3">
         <p class="tree_item leaf">
            <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1230"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;REFRESH</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="type_unknown depth_3" id="yui_3_15_0_4_1495615549528_187">
         <p class="tree_item leaf wiki_newentry" id="yui_3_15_0_4_1495615549528_186">
            <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1167"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;REFRESH</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="type_unknown depth_3">
         <p class="tree_item leaf">
            <a href="http://moodlelive.dev/mod/wiki/view.php?pageid=1270"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-spacer"></span> &nbsp;REFRESH</a>
        </p>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Is this also possible with + and - icon and only make that button clickable? (Not the text)

Comment: @nielsv  yes it's possible